# How to import API part of pdfcpu library

Tags: go, pdf, pdfcpu

I try to use API part of pdfcpu from github (https://github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu) to read PDF metadata, but I don't know how to import it to program. When I wrote

```
import (
       github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu
)
```

and type **go build**, I've received error message:

```
readpdf.go:5:9: no required module provides package github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu; to add it:
        go get github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu
```

After executing **go get** and try to build again - the situation not change, still the same message.

I've checked in ~/go/pkg/mod exists **~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu@v0.3.9/**

The go version is 1.16 and go.mod looks like:

```
module vctl.eu/pdfgoa

go 1.16

require github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu v0.3.9 // indirect
```

Comment: `github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu` isn't a go package, you cannot import that path. Did you look at the [link to the API documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu/pkg/api)?

Comment: Yes, but there is only short description of functions. And install instruction is for cmd part, not for API, which seems to be in pkg/api  subdirecotry of project.

Comment: There is no "installation" of the package, you just have to import it correctly. Like you said, it's in the `pkg/api` subdirectory: `github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu/pkg/api`

Answer (score 4):

After using `go get github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu` you just need to import the package like this:

```
package main


import (
    "github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu/pkg/api"
)

func main() {
    api.ReadContext(...)
    ...
}
```

You can even rename the import by prepending a new name in the import statement and use it like this

```
package main

import (
    pdfcpu "github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu/pkg/api"
)

func main() {
    pdfcpu.ReadContext(...)
    ...
}
```